# Wordpress in subfolder dont work

Tags: installation

we have wordpress main site on domain.com 
now we did copy of the site and put in the sub-folder domain.com/blog
we did all necessary url changes. 
but it seems we have issues with .htaccess file.. the domain.com/blog is redirected to domain.com

this is what .htaccess in root

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

this is what .htaccess in /blog folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

whats wrong with them?
thanks a lot

Comment: WordPress.org have this well documented: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: Maybe you left the old `.htaccess` in the root dir? Or some too cramped SSL `RewriteRule`? Or you site's Apache conf?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.htaccess` looks just fine, but you need to tell WordPress itself that it got moved. Simply put the following line into your `wp-config.php`, then access your site's login page under the new URL and login. After that you can remove this line.:

```
define('RELOCATE', TRUE);
```

---

Alternatively add the following two lines to your `wp-config.php`, then navigate through the site a few pages far, then you can remove these lines.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://domain.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://domain.com/blog');
```

---

Source: [Changing The Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Answer (score -1):

You need to Re-Check following two:

1. SITEURL and Home in database table wp_options
2. settings in wp-config.php

   To learn more about check WordPress [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)